# cabal-version option ignored

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to install a fairly old package (see [here](https://github.com/michael-swan/hs-skia)) with stack. It uses a custom `Setup.hs` script which depends on `cabal >= 1.20` due to (among other things) a reliance on the `buildNumJobs` field of the `BuildFlags` type.

For some reason, the `cabal-version` was set to `>= 1.10` which is clearly too low. I changed it once I figured out what was going on, but the problem persisted. What do I have to do for stack and cabal to pick up on the new `cabal-version` constraint?

I tried simply replacing the `buildNumJobs` value with a default value, which resulted in the following error at build time:

```
Warning: skia.cabal: This package requires at least Cabal version 1.20
Configuring skia-0.1.0.0...
setup.EXE: This package description follows version 1.20 of the Cabal
specification. This tool only supports up to version 1.18.1.5.
```

Again, what do I need to do for stack to respect the `cabal-version` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, all I had to do was to run `stack setup --upgrade-cabal`. I still wonder though why stack doesn't detect the inconsistency automatically...